# How to use union type in typscript?

Tags: typescript, union

```
interface A {
  name : string;
  age : number;
}

interface B {
  name: string;
  address: string;
}

public samplefunction(data : A | B) : A | B{
  switch(data.name)
      case("John"):
          console.log(data.age),　// ✖ Property 'age' does not exist on type...
      case("Kim"):
          console.log(data.address), //✖ Property 'address' does not exist on type
    ....
}
```

Why error occur at console.log error?

In this sample code, I would like to know how to use user union type.

Is this union type method correct?

understand union type

Comment: Use `extends` to merge the properties of interface `A` and interface `B`, not a union.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can't assume `data` has an `age` property until you first narrow it from `A | B` to `A`.  Like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDV3lW) maybe.  The code here is unfortunately pseudocode or has typos, and the logic of only checking `age` for `"John"` and `address` for `"Kim"` is hard for me to understand.  In any case, please check the answers to the linked questions for more information.

Comment: thanks everybody. I resolved this problem.